# pandas groupby then filter by date to get mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mean

Using pandas dataframes and I'm attempting to get the average number of purchases in the last 90 days for each row(not including the current row itself) based on CustId and then add a new column "PurchaseMeanLast90Days".

This is the code I tried, which is incorrect:

```
group = df.groupby(['CustId'])
df['PurchaseMeanLast90Days'] = group.apply(lambda g: g[g['Date'] > (pd.DatetimeIndex(g['Date']) + pd.DateOffset(-90))])['Purchases'].mean()
```

Here's my data:

| Index | CustId | Date | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1/01/2021 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 1/12/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3/28/2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4/01/2021 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 4/20/2021 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 5/01/2021 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 1/01/2021 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 2/01/2021 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 3/01/2021 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 4/01/2021 | 3 |

For example, row index 5 would include these rows in it's mean() = 3.33

| Index | CustId | Date | Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3/28/2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4/01/2021 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 4/20/2021 | 2 |

The new dataframe would look like this(I didn't do the calcs for CustId=2):

| Index | CustId | Date | Purchases | PurchaseMeanLast90Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1/09/2021 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1/12/2021 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 3/28/2021 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4/01/2021 | 4 | 2.67 |
| 4 | 1 | 4/20/2021 | 2 | 3.0 |
| 5 | 1 | 5/01/2021 | 5 | 3.33 |
| 6 | 2 | 1/01/2021 | 1 | ... |
| 7 | 2 | 2/01/2021 | 1 | ... |
| 8 | 2 | 3/01/2021 | 2 | ... |
| 9 | 2 | 4/01/2021 | 3 | ... |

Comment: Are you sure that index `4` is correctly computed? Between `4/20/2021` and `1/12/2021` is 98 days. So it should be `3.0`, not `2.33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a rolling computation:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=False)
df["PurchaseMeanLast90Days"] = (
    (
        df.groupby("CustId")
        .rolling("90D", min_periods=1, on="Date", closed="both")["Purchases"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).sum() / (len(x) - 1))
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .values
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Index  CustId       Date  Purchases  PurchaseMeanLast90Days
0      0       1 2021-01-01          5                0.000000
1      1       1 2021-01-12          1                5.000000
2      2       1 2021-03-28          2                3.000000
3      3       1 2021-04-01          4                2.666667
4      4       1 2021-04-20          2                3.000000
5      5       1 2021-05-01          5                2.666667
6      6       2 2021-01-01          1                0.000000
7      7       2 2021-02-01          1                1.000000
8      8       2 2021-03-01          2                1.000000
9      9       2 2021-04-01          3                1.333333
```